# Reaction of copper (II) ion reacting with sodium hydroxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, identification

Based on an experiment, a solution that contained $\ce{Cu^2+}$ formed a precipitate with $\ce{NaOH}$. Is this how you write the equation?

$$\ce{2NaOH + Cu^{2+} -> Cu(OH)2 + 2Na+}$$

On the experiment: solution A is mixed with NaOH (solution turned white). Using a flame test solution A is color green. I figured solution A has $\ce{Cu^{2+}}$ ion.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the reaction is correct however it may be preferable to either include *all* or *no* spectator ions.
Use either a net ionic equations (omit the Na+), molecular equation (include the copper compound full) or complete ionic equation.

For example, if the compound is copper sulphate the equations would be (without states)

**Net ionic**
$$\ce{Cu^2+}+\ce{2OH^-->Cu(OH)_2}$$
**Molecular equation**
$$\ce{CuSO_4}+\ce{2NaOH->Cu(OH)_2}+\ce{Na_2SO_4}$$
**Complete Ionic Equation**
$$\ce{Cu^2+ +SO_4^{2-}}+\ce{2Na^+ +2OH^-->Cu(OH)_2}+\ce{2Na^+ +SO_4^2-}$$

**Edit**

In the case where you don't know what copper compound it is, use a net ionic equation. As a side note, copper hydroxide is not white. You might want to check your calculations.

If you're wondering what it is, check what other compounds will emit green.

Comment: Usually a ppt is indicated in a chemical reaction as: $$\ce{Cu(OH)2 v}$$ or $$\ce{Cu(OH)2_{(s)}}$$ Also dissolved ionic species can be indicated so: $$\ce{Na2SO4_{(aq)}}$$.